# Cache key lookup -- finding the "closest" or identical key

Tags: php, caching, string-matching

**Edit**: I approached this question in an implementation agnostic way, however here's the nitty-gritty on what I'm after.

I have a set of functions, that perform read and write operations on arrays, permitting the following syntax:

```
$map->{'foo.bar.baz'}; // same as $array['foo']['bar']['baz'];
```

Even in a sensitive error reporting environment, no notices are thrown in absence of the targeted array element, returning `null` instead. Anyways, to improve access performance, I've added caching functionality to the read methods.

The cache is invalidated (*and cleared*) whenever a write operation is performed, but repeated reads (*to the same element at this point*) show a considerable performance improvement. The cached "value", is a reference to the array element, rather than a copy of the element's value.

The function(s) work by iterating through an exploded string (*the array element path*) such as `foo.bar.baz` finding (*if it exists*) `$array['foo']['bar']['baz']`.

Right now the cache is simply an associative array of paths (*keys*) referencing the appropriate elements of the given array, such as:

```
'foo' => &$array['foo'],
'foo.bar' => &$array['foo']['bar'],
```

However, I was thinking I could further improve cache performance by finding references to the closest parent of a given path, rather than that path specifically. For example:

```
// given
$map->{'foo.bar'}; // read operation

// followed by
$map->{'foo.bar.baz.zip'}; // another read operation
```

Since no key exists in the cache for `foo.bar.baz.zip` it would have to perform a whole new fetch against the array. I was hoping I could take advantage of the stored reference to `foo.bar` and just perform a fetch of `baz.zip` against that.

All this adds up to finding the closest string match up to, and including the current path being read.

[`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/levenshtein) seems like a fitting possibility (*as perscribed by @mfonda - thank you by the way*) if wrapped with some preliminary checks to avoid unnecessary iterations, but I've noticed that due to the way that it diffs two strings, it will sometimes return invalid matches, finding `foo.zoo` for `foo.bar.zoo` over `foo.bar`.

---

Quick one; I'm looking for the quickest way to match a string, to find the closest (*or identical*) from an array of strings (*keys*), by why I mean:

```
// given
$string = 'foo.bar.baz';

// and
$list_1 = array(
    'foo' => null
    'foo.bar.baz.zip' => null,
);

// and
$list_2 = array(
    'foo' => null,
    'foo.bar' => null,
    'foo.goo.baz' => null,
);

// and
$list_3 = array(
    'foo.bar.baz' => null,
    'foo.bar.baz.zip' => null,
);

// yields
echo magic_match($string, $list_1); // foo
echo magic_match($string, $list_2); // foo.bar
echo magic_match($string, $list_3); // foo.bar.baz
```

The string "closeness" is determined by the longest string, not longer than the check string, that matches. So `abc` checked against `a` and `abcd` matches `a`, as `abcd` exceeds the length of the check.

I'm doing some tests now, but I'm sure a PHP dev in the SO community has devised something already.

It appears (*unfortunately*) there is no native function in PHP to do this; between [`strstr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), [`preg_grep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) (*which doesn't do the job anyways*) and an odd combination of alternatives, nothing seems particularly fast.

---

At this point, to determine if `$string` exists exactly (*or doesn't*) we could start with:

```
if(!isset($list[$string])){
    // proceed with processing to find closest
}else{
    // identical found
}
```

Since the string is delimited with `.`, we could `explode()` the string and implode progressively:

```
$parts = explode('.', $string);
while(!empty($parts)){
    if(isset($list[$string = implode('.', $parts))]){
        break;
    }
    array_pop($parts);
}
```

However, persistently re-imploding the string through the iterations could prove costly.

Comment: Why is `foo` closer to `foo.bar.baz` than `foo.bar.baz.zip`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - Good point; didn't explain that, check for edit momentarily.

Comment: What if you try to match `foo` against `foo1` and `foo2`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - Both fail, `foo1` and `foo2` exceed the length of `foo`. However between `f` and `fo`, `fo` would win. I know I mentioned the delimitation of the strings by `.`, however unless that provides a processing advantage, it's irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: How about `foo` against `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - Again, neither. The tested string must be equal to all or part (*from the beginning*) of the check string. `substr()` with an negatively iterated length would work, but that would in fact be more iterations than the `explode() -> implode()` version in the edit (*despite ex/implosion function being seemingly costly*)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `strstr()`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - `strstr()` simply doesn't do what I want, I'm trying to make it though, massaging the data into something useable.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/similar_text) or [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/levenshtein). These functions will give you a measure of how similar two strings are. Based on this, you could choose the closest match.

Comment: Thanks @mfonda - `levenshtein()` nearly works; it sometimes returns invalid results though - it returns `foo.baz` instead of `foo.bar` for a query of `foo.bar.baz`. I'm still playing with `similar_text()` but I'm really aiming for speed here, as the purpose is to do a cache hit. If it ends up being more expensive than the full fetch, then I'm better off with my naive look-up.

Comment: @Bracketworks `levenshtein()` calculates the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings. This is definitely **not** what you are looking for.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - Well, it worked under a number of circumstances, but as in my example it failed; I'm not entirely familiar with it so I'll read up anyhow. Thanks for the wiki.

Comment: @Bracketworks my answer really does not make sense after you redefined your question. Just use explode/isset.

Answer (score 0):

Well your matching criteria are somewhat fuzzy. So you're probably going to have to do this yourself. I see there being different cases, depending on the lengths. So how about:

```
function magic_match($str, $list) {
   $scores = array();
   foreach($list as $item) {

      if (strlen($str) > strlen($item) {
         // one type of compare
         $scores[] = array($item, $score);
      }
      else {
         // other type
         $scores[] = array($item, $score);
      }
   }

   // return item with highest score
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart - I'm not quite getting the scores.